# Como forçar o recaptcha a expirar sua sessão?

Tags: recaptcha

Estou tentando fazer modificações com a mensagem de expiração do recaptcha, porém não consigo vê-la (ocasionamente se eu deixar uma aba aberta, ela aparece), existe alguma maneira de forçar o callback de expiração do recaptcha?

No caso abaixo o alert não é executado porque não sei qual o tempo para ele ser ativado.

```
var onloadCallback = function() {
     grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
          'sitekey' : '6LcaNiwUAAAAAEdD5whzKq-9b1cXMlLexxBxcXhO',
          'expired-callback' : expCallback
        });
  };

 var expCallback = function() {
      alert('ok');
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Não há como forçar o recaptcha a expirar sessão, apenas renderiza-la após expirar.

Use um parâmetro de retorno de chamada usando `grecaptcha.reset()`

Por exemplo:

Coloque isso no cabeçalho.

```
<script>
   var callback = function() {
      grecaptcha.render('id-of-render-element', {
         'sitekey': 'your-site-key',
         'expired-callback': expCallback
       });
   };
   var expCallback = function() {
      grecaptcha.reset();
   };
</script>
```

Coloque isso depois do elemento que será usado para renderizar o reCAPTCHA.

```
<div id="id-of-render-element"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=callback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738949/fire-event-when-recaptcha-session-expires